# The statement on nonseparable metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

If the metric space is nonseparable then there is uncountable subset  $N$ such that $d(x,y) > c$ for some $c$ and any $x,y \in N$.

I suppose the only way is to suppose converse come to contradiction, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hint. Let $\varepsilon\gt0.$ If there is no uncountable subset $N$ such that $d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon$ for all $x,y\in N,\ x\ne y,$ then there is a countable subset $M_\varepsilon$ such that for every $x$ in the space there is a point $y\in M_\varepsilon$ with $d(x,y)\le\varepsilon.$

Comment: How it follows from  converse statement? Suppose there is no such $N$, why there is $M_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: $M$ is for Maximal.

Comment: Let $M_\varepsilon$ be a ***maximal*** subset $M$ with the property that the distance between any two points of $M$ is greater than $\varepsilon.$

Comment: By the way, I think that by "converse" you mean "negation".

Comment: I understand part  "greater than ε", but how do you get $d(x,y) \leq $ $\epsilon $?

Comment: If there is a point $x$ such that $d(x,y)\gt\varepsilon$ for all $y\in M$ then $M$ is not maximal, $M\subset M\cup\{x\}.$